# chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener Is Not Working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this HTML file hosted in my server :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            $( document ).ready(function() {

                var editorExtensionId = "fblmefappkgpogjehblfmlhfnfpnnlep";
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage( editorExtensionId, "Eat This!" );

                alert("perfect!"); << ** this show up, so I assume sending message to chrome runtime also works **

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's my `manifest` file :

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mydomain.com/*", "*://mydomain.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
],

"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.mydomain.com/*", "*://mydomain.com/*"]
}
```

and here's my `myscript.js` file :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert (request);
});
```

everytime I open `mydomain.com` there's no alert from `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener`. It seems that `myscript.js` is not 'listening' to anything and failed to receive message from jquery. what did I missed here? thank you.

Comment: The documentation says [onMessageExternal cannot be used in a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal). Do it in a background/event page.

Comment: IT WORKS, BRO!!! thank you so much!